# Create a board of random integers 1..6 with no more than two adjacent repeated values

Tags: python

First, here is my code:

```
import random
Tablero = []
for i in range(0,20):
   Tablero.append( [0]*9 )
for Fila in range(20):
    for Columna in range(9):
        Tablero[Fila][Columna] = random.randint(1,6)

for i in range (0,20): 
    for j in range (0, 9) : 
        print(str.rjust(str(Tablero[i][j]), 4), end = "")
    print();
input()
```

And the current output:

```
   3   5   5   2   6   2   2   3   6
   6   2   5   3   4   1   6   4   5
   1   5   4   2   1   4   6   6   6
   4   6   6   2   1   3   5   6   1
   5   2   2   1   1   4   5   6   1
   3   6   3   1   6   2   6   2   6
   1   1   5   2   6   5   3   6   5
   1   2   1   6   1   3   4   1   6
   5   2   3   2   1   6   3   4   3
   4   6   6   6   6   6   5   1   2
   4   4   5   4   3   6   5   1   3
   4   5   1   2   2   3   5   2   5
   1   2   4   5   2   2   3   2   4
   2   1   5   3   4   1   2   4   6
   1   3   3   4   4   4   6   5   6
   6   6   2   2   3   1   6   3   3
   1   5   6   4   2   6   2   1   4
   2   3   5   5   6   6   2   4   4
   5   5   1   6   1   2   5   4   4
   2   3   6   5   4   6   2   2   3
```

Problem: there are cases where the same numbers appear more than 3 times in a row, this only matters for the COLUMNS.
Example:

```
1   3   3   4   4   4   6   5   6
```

And it should be:

```
1   3   3   4   4   2   4   2   6
```

I am trying this code for like a week... I was able to do it separately but adding it to this program did not work.
A simple code would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: The program is similar to the game candy crush. In this program, only the columns matter when adding points, that is to say, only these have to be aligned (3,3,3) would be equivalent to a certain score. Therefore, the program should not generate this : 1   3   3   4   4   4   6   5   6, because otherwise it would play on its own. Since then, one must enter the row and column of a number which will be eliminated and that in that position will fall the number that is above.

Comment: What are you exact requirements? Spell them out in your question. What is your definition of "*random*"?

Comment: Seems pretty clear the OP meant *"with no more than two adjacent repeated values"* (in any row). Please edit the title if it can be improved.

Comment: @Pedro, welcome to SO. I would like to ask you to phrase your question better. For example, it would be better if the problem statement is defined before you start explaining the code. Also, it is confusing that in your title do you want a board with at max two same numbers adjacent to each other? What is the meaning of adjacent and other questions. Please rephrase it so that others can help you out.

Comment: It seems my answer isn't what you're looking for so I'll remove it.